# Subclass avoiding parent's metaclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, subclass, metaclass, subclassing

Say I have a third-party library where a metaclass requires me to implement something. But I want to have an intermediate "abstract" subclass that doesn't. How can I do this?

Consider this to be a very minimal example of what third-party library has:

```
class ServingMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, classdict):
        if any(isinstance(b, ServingMeta) for b in bases):
            if "name" not in classdict:
                # Actual code fails for a different reason,
                # but the logic is the same.
                raise TypeError(f"Class '{name}' has no 'name' attribute")
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, classdict)

class Serving(object, metaclass=ServingMeta):
    def shout_name(self):
        return self.name.upper()
```

**I cannot modify the code above.** It's an external dependency (and I don't want to fork it).

The code is meant to be used this way:

```
class Spam(Serving):
    name = "SPAM"

spam = Spam()
print(spam.shout_name())
```

However, I happen to have a lot of spam, and I want to introduce a base class with the common helper methods. Something like this:

```
class Spam(Serving):
    def thrice(self):
        return " ".join([self.shout_name()] * 3)

class LovelySpam(Spam):
    name = "lovely spam"

class WonderfulSpam(Spam):
    name = "wonderful spam"
```

Obviously, this doesn't work and fails with the well-expected `TypeError: Class 'SpamBase' has no 'name' attribute declared`. Would third-party library had a `SpamBase` class without a metaclass, I could've subclassed that - but no such luck this time (I've mentioned this inconvenience to the library authors).

I can make it a mixin:

```
class SpamMixin(object):
    def thrice(self):
        return " ".join([self.shout_name()] * 3)

class LovelySpam(SpamMixin, Serving):
    name = "lovely spam"

class WonderfulSpam(SpamMixin, Serving):
    name = "wonderful spam"
```

However, this makes me and my IDE cringe a little, as it quickly becomes cumbersome to repeat `SpamMixin` everywhere and also because `object` has no `shout_name` attribute (and I don't want to silence analysis tools). In short, I just don't like this approach.

**What else can I do?**

Is there a way to get a metaclass-less version of `Serving`? I think of something like this:

```
ServingBase = remove_metaclass(Serving)

class Spam(ServingBase, metaclass=ServingMeta):
    ...
```

But don't know how to actually implement `remove_metaclass` and whenever it's even reasonably possible (of course, it must be doable, with some introspection, but it could require more arcane magic than I can cast).

Any other suggestions are also welcomed. Basically, I want to have my code DRY (one base class to rule them all), and have my linter/code analysis icons all green.

Comment: I think you could try rebuilding the type object using `type`: `ServingBase = type('ServingBase', Serving.__bases__, dict(vars(Serving)))` I'd argue that a mixin would make the code cleaner, though

Comment: @vaultah Yes, I haven't thought about this. Looks to be an option. Can you post this as an answer? I'll wait for other suggestions, but want to be able to mark yours as an accepted answer if there won't be any better suggestions. As for the cleanliness - personally, I feel that if things are reasonably decorated with the self-descriptive names (`ServingBase`, `remove_metaclass`) and well-commented, then it should be okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mixin approach is the correct way to go. If your IDE "cringe" that is a deffect on that tool - just disable a little of the "features" that are obviously incorrect tunning when coding for a dynamic language like Python.

And this is not even about creating things dynamically, it is merely multiple-inheritance, which is supported by the language since forever. And one of the main uses of multiple-inheritance is exactly being able to create mixins just as this one you need.

Another inheritance-based workaround is to make your hierarchy one level deeper, and just introduce the metaclass after you come up with your mixin methods:

```
class Mixin(object):
    def mimixin(self): ...

class SpamBase(Mixin, metaclass=ServingMeta):
    name = "stub"
```

Or just addd the mixin in an intermediate subclass:

```
class Base(metaclass=Serving Meta):
     name = "stub"
class MixedBase(Mixin, Base):
     name = "stub"
class MyLovingSpam(MixedBase):
     name = "MyLovingSpam"
```

If you don't want to be repeating the mixin=-base name in every class, that is the way to go.

"Removing" a metaclass just for the sake of having a late mixin is way over the top.  Really. Broken. The way to do it wol e re-create the class dynamically, just as @vaultah mentions in the other answer, but doing that in an intermediate class is a thing you should not do. Doing that to please the IDE is something you should not do twice: messing with metaclasses is hard enough already. Removing things on inheritance/class creation that the language puts there naturally is something nasty (cf. this answer: [How to make a class attribute exclusive to the super class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021908/how-to-make-a-class-attribute-exclusive-to-the-super-class/43025065#43025065) ) . On the other hand, mixins and multiple inheritance are just natural.

## Are you still there? I told you not to do so:

Now, onto your question - instead of "supressing the metaclass"  in an intermediate class, it would be more feasible to inherit the metaclass you have there and change its behavior - so that it does not check for the constraints in specially marked classes - create an attribute for your use, like `_skip_checking`

```
class MyMeta(ServingMeta):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace):
         if namespace.get("_skip_checking", False):
              # hardcode call to "type" metaclass:
              del namespace["_skip_checking"]
              cls = type.__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace)
         else:
              cls = super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace) 
         return cls
     # repeat for __init__ if needed.  


class Base(metaclass=MyMeta):
     _skip_checking = True
     # define mixin methods

class LoveSpam(Base):
    name = "LoveSpam"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You've perusaded me, I'll stick with mixins (and ask library authors to consider having a separate base class). I think IDE (PyCharm) was still correct to warn that I may trip on using a method which existence is uncertain - but it's the particular warnings that need to be disabled. A trick to avoid metaclass could be useful in some other situations, and I guess subclassing it is probably the sanest way to go with insanity. :) So I'll mark your answer as accepted, in both cases. Once again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no direct way to remove the metaclass from a Python class, because the metaclass *created* that class. What you can try is re-create the class using a different metaclass, which doesn't have unwanted behaviour. For example, you could use `type` (the default metaclass).

```
In [6]: class Serving(metaclass=ServingMeta):
   ...:     def shout_name(self):
   ...:         return self.name.upper()
   ...: 

In [7]: ServingBase = type('ServingBase', Serving.__bases__, dict(vars(Serving)))
```

Basically this takes the `__bases__` tuple and the namespace of the `Serving` class, and uses them to create a new class `ServingBase`. N.B. this means that `ServingBase` will receive all bases and methods/attributes from `Serving`, some of which may have been added by `ServingMeta`.